# Windows forms navigate webrowser method not available?

Tags: windows, phalanger

I try to navigate to a url and send a new http header with phalanger but when I use the navigate method it gives me an error message there is no method available (even with overload and so). How can I send my own http header? Example:

This dosesn't work:
    this->browser->Navigate(new \System\Uri($url),"_self",null, $authHeader);

This works (but it navigates only to the website w/o sending my header:

```
this->browser->Navigate(new \System\Uri($url),$authHeader);
```

Edit: This works, too, and is the more correct approach but I want the thing with the additional header!!!

this->browser->Navigate(new \System\Uri($url));

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.Navigate() has four overloads, neither of them has two arguments. Did you try this one? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee169602(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know it has 4 overloads but none of them works. Your example mostly like works but it also works with 2 overloads.